# Qt Can't set centralWidget() properly

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to build a simple GUI application. Then I got those warnings:

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "", which already has a layout
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "", which already has a layout
```

I googled that you have to set central widget in `MainWindow`. And here is my implement which is still not working:

.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QWidget *centralWidget;

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void setButtons();
    ...
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPushButton *btn[9][9];
}
```

.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    ...
}

void MainWindow::setButtons()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            btn[i][j] = new QPushButton(this);
            ...
            QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
            vLayout->addWidget(btn[i][j]);
            centralWidget->setLayout(vLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

After trying this, I still received the warning messages, how can I solve this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947375/qt-compiler-complains-when-invoking-setlayout-on-my-mainwindow help?

Comment: @RvdK I've seen that already, and I tried to implement like that. But not working.

Comment: For me, it compiles and runs without any errors or warnings. Have you tried to completely rebuild the project? Remove the build directory and compile again.

Comment: @pasbi yes, I tried what you said, don't know why it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two basic issues.  Firstly, the statement...

```
 QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
```

will instantiate a new `QVBoxLayout` with `this` as its parent.  Since `this` is of type `MainWindow *` and `MainWindow` inherits from `QMainWindow` you are effectively calling `QMainWindow::setLayout` -- that's the source of the error message...

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "", which already
>   has a layout

Secondly, you're creating a new `QVBoxLayout` on each loop iteration.  If you really do want the buttons vertically aligned in a layout try something like...

```
void MainWindow::setButtons ()
{
  QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      btn[i][j] = new QPushButton;
        ...
      vLayout->addWidget(btn[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Now the QLayout error is gone, but the QWidget is still there. Do you know how to solve that? BTW, I tried to follow your example code, after I ran this, the buttons are not showing, why?

Comment: Are you *definitely* calling `MainWindow::setButtons` somewhere?  I assumed the call would be somewhere in the elided `...` code.  For what it's worth I've tested the code and it appears to work as expected -- lots of buttons and no error message.